# 500 Error when using Apache Directory Directive

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory

I am trying to restrict access to certain directories to certain IP's.... I have done some research & the below is what I came up with, however it returns a 500 internal server error when I try & access the page..

```
<Directory "/home/username/public_html/admin/">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 123.45.67.89
    allow from 111.222.333.444
    allow from 123.45.*.*
    allow from 123.44.*.*
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/username/public_html/blog/wp-admin/">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 123.45.67.89
    allow from 111.222.333.444
    allow from 123.45.*.*
    allow from 123.44.*.*
</Directory>
```

What did I do wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

That's not [how IP address ranges in the `Allow` directive work](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow).  The * symbol is not in the docs.

You can either write:

```
Allow from 123.45
```

or

```
Allow from 123.45.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

or

```
Allow from 123.45.0.0/16
```

There are other allowed syntax but I find the CIDR notation to be the clearest and most readable.